# Gráfico con las horas del día en el EJE X con Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Quiero generar un gráfico en el cual el eje X sean las horas de un día, es decir algo como este ejemplo que hay en la web de Matplotlib pero en vez de la fecha, las horas en plan 00:00, 01:00......22:00, 23:00

El ejemplo sería este:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load some financial data; apple's stock price
with cbook.get_sample_data('aapl.npz') as fh:
r = np.load(fh)['price_data'].view(np.recarray)
r = r[-250:]  # get the last 250 days
date = r.date.astype('O')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(date, r.adj_close)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.MonthLocator(bymonthday=15))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.NullFormatter())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b'))

for tick in ax.xaxis.get_minor_ticks():
    tick.tick1line.set_markersize(0)
    tick.tick2line.set_markersize(0)
    tick.label1.set_horizontalalignment('center')

imid = len(r) // 2
ax.set_xlabel(str(date[imid].year))
plt.show()
```

Puede ser así como ese de tendencia o de barras, con el gráfico me gustaría indicar cuantas veces ocurre un evento a ciertas horas del día.

Comment: El dataset que usas en el ejemplo no contiene horas del día, solo fechas. Es imposible a partir del mismo obtener estadísticas por horas ¿Tienes tú un dataset en que los datos vengan con estampas de tiempo por horas? En ese caso, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que has intentado con tu dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Hice una versión más reducida del caso:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import shuffle, randint
import matplotlib.dates as dates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

formato = dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")
dias = [datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(10)]
precios =[randint(1,100) for x in enumerate(dias)]
shuffle(precios)

plt.plot(dias, precios)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formato)
plt.show()
```

El efecto deseado se consigue definiendo un **formato** de horas y minutos para este caso:

> formato = dates.DateFormatter("%H:%M")

Y aplicándolo al eje x del gráfico:

> plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(formato)

Creo que para el código que pusiste como ejemplo no te servirá el formato, puesto que en tu variable **date** tiene la fecha sin la hora.

Comment: Hola RodrigoN, y como puedo hacer para que salgan las 24 horas del día en el ejeX???

Comment: Alfredo, al menos de esta forma, tienes que tener la misma cantidad de elementos en ambos ejes. Si quieres 24 horas, también tendras que tener 24 precios. El el ejemplo sería cambiar range(10) por range(**24**).